# Add datetime to the export file name when using to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I try

```
snapshotdate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
os.chdir('/Users/Jason/Desktop')
df.to_csv(open(snapshotdata+'.csv','w'),index=none)
```

and get an error No such file or directory: '02/19/2017.csv'. '02/19/2017.csv' is exactly what I want to get. How can I do it while using to_csv()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use slashes in your filename.
You're trying to create the file *2017.csv* in subdirectory *19* of dir *02*, who don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I change 
    snapshotdate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
to
    snapshotdate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

It works now.